# VBA Validate input in the input box

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I need an input box that will provide a value that is an enumerator. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468(v=office.15).aspx) Does not mention validating the fields at all.

Is there a way of doing that? Like in HTML5 the `pattern` in `input` tag?

Here is snippet of my relevant code.

```
Enum Scope
    Cell = 1
    Row = 2
    Column = 3
End Enum
.... some other code ...
Used_Scope = Application.InputBox( _
    Title:="higlight scope", _
    Prompt:="Enter Row, Column, or Cell to decide what to higlight", _
    Type:=2)
```

Comment: You'd like the input to be validated?

Comment: Yes but the catch is that I was hoping  validate it as user is entering the information not after he presses enter.

Comment: Have you found a solution or tried out the user form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a UserForm. I don't believe InputBox has the functionality you're looking for.

Here is a sample UserForm along with the code for your functionality.

[image]

```
Sub call_uform()

UserForm1.Show

Used_Scope = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text

Unload UserForm1


End Sub


    Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Used_Scope = TextBox1.Value

    Me.Hide

    End Sub

        Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

        OnlyNumbers

        End Sub

        Private Sub OnlyNumbers()


            If TypeName(Me.ActiveControl) = "TextBox" Then

                With Me.ActiveControl

                    If Not IsNumeric(.Value) And .Value <> vbNullString Then

                        MsgBox "Sorry, only numbers allowed"

                        .Value = vbNullString

                    End If

                End With

            End If

        End Sub

        Private Sub UserForm_Click()

        End Sub
```